# how to Achieve in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

the visualforce page I write are shown below，I want to when click Edit button the corresponding row can be editable,the edit style like LineInSupport tag.
[image]
here is my visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="SelectedPrimaryContactController" tabStyle="Contact">
    <script>
        function Save(node)
        {
            var checkedIds = new Array();
            var ids = document.getElementsByName("contactIds");
            for(i = 0; i < ids.length; i ++)
            {   
                if(ids[i].checked == true)
                {   
                    checkedIds.push(ids[i].value); 
                }
            }
            if(checkedIds.length == 0)
            {   
                alert('You must choose one.');
                return;
            }
            else
            {   
                passContactIdsToController(JSON.stringify(checkedIds));     
            }
        }   
    </script>
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Selected Primary Contact"></apex:sectionHeader>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlock title="Selected Primary Contact" id="allCountacts" mode="inlineEdit">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1"> 
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!Contacts}" var="Contact" id="table">
                        <apex:column headervalue="Action">
                            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!Contact.PrimaryBox__c}">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="contactIds" value="{!Contact.Id}" checked="checked"/>
                                <apex:commandLink value="Edit" action="{!editContact}" rerender="table" immediate="true" status="loading" >
                                    <apex:param name="contactId" value="{!Contact.Id}" assignTo="{!ContactId}"/>
                                </apex:commandLink>
                                &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                <apex:commandLink value="Del" action="{!delContact}" rerender="table" immediate="true" status="loading" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){return false;}">
                                    <apex:param name="contactId" value="{!Contact.Id}" assignTo="{!ContactId}"/>
                                </apex:commandLink>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(Contact.PrimaryBox__c)}">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="contactIds" value="{!Contact.Id}"/>
                                <apex:commandLink value="Edit" action="{!editContact}" rerender="table" immediate="true" status="loading" >
                                    <apex:param name="contactId" value="{!Contact.Id}" assignTo="{!ContactId}"/>
                                </apex:commandLink>
                               &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                <apex:commandLink value="Del" action="{!delContact}" rerender="table" immediate="true" status="loading" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){return false;}">
                                    <apex:param name="contactId" value="{!Contact.Id}" assignTo="{!ContactId}"/>
                                </apex:commandLink>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headervalue="Name">
                            <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.FirstName}">
                                <apex:inlineEditSupport/>
                            </apex:outputField>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headervalue="Email" value="{!Contact.Email}"/>
                        <apex:column headervalue="Title" value="{!Contact.Title}" />
                        <apex:column headervalue="Phone" value="{!Contact.Phone}"/>
                    </apex:pageblocktable>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" id="saveButton" onclick="Save(); return false;" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!canceled}"/>
        <apex:actionFunction name="passContactIdsToController" action="{!selected}" rerender="view">
            <apex:param id="anode" name="node" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

here is my controller:

```
public class SelectedPrimaryContactController { 
    private String accountId;

    public SelectedPrimaryContactController()
    {
        accountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accountId');
        loadContacts();
    }

    public List<Contact> Contacts {get; set;}
    public String ContactId {get; set;}

    public void loadContacts() 
    {       
        Contacts = [select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Title, Phone, PrimaryBox__c from Contact where Contact.AccountId = :accountId order by Name];  
    }

    public void delContact()
    {   
        delete [select Id, Name, Email, Title, Phone, PrimaryBox__c from Contact where Id = :ContactId];
        loadContacts();
    }

    public PageReference selected()
    {
        List<String> selectedContactIds = (List<String>)JSON.deserialize(Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('node'), List<string>.class);
        Set<String> selectedContactIdsSet = new Set<String>(selectedContactIds);
        for(Contact contact : Contacts)
        {   
            if(selectedContactIdsSet.contains(contact.Id))
            {
                contact.PrimaryBox__c = true;       
            }
            else
            {
                contact.PrimaryBox__c = false;
            }          
        }
        update Contacts;
        return new PageReference('/' + accountId);
    }

    public void editContact()
    {

    } 

    public PageReference canceled()
    {
        return new PageReference('/' + accountId);         
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to add more details to your question, you may [edit] it.

Answer (score -1):

i have a page and controller for you, you can see how we can edit and delete account easily.may be it will be help full.

```
3. Account list with dynamic edit and delete operation on the selected list
  - wrapper class 
      account
      checkbox field boolean
  -method to show via wrapper
  - delete function
  - edit function using rendered on condition, in ediatbale/ output format
  - button del/edit save/cancel


/* Page apex */

<apex:page controller="CListView" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
   <apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:actionstatus id="status">
            <apex:facet name="start"> 
                <img class="waitingImage" src="/img/loading.gif" title="Please Wait..." />
                <span class="waitingDescription">Please Wait...</span>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionstatus>
       <apex:actionFunction name="enableEdit" action="{!editSelect}" status="status" rerender="frm"/>
        <apex:actionFunction name="saveIt"  action="{!saveAcc}" status="status" rerender="frm"/> 
       <apex:actionFunction name="cancelIt"  action="{!cancelAcc}"  status="status" rerender="frm"/>
      <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="block" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Accounts" id="table"  columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" var="a" id="table">
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.isSelected}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!a.ac.Name}" rendered="{!(!a.isSelected)}"/>
                    <apex:column rendered="{!a.isSelected}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!a.ac.Name}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!a.ac.Industry}" rendered="{!(!a.isSelected)}"/>
                    <apex:column rendered="{!a.isSelected}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!a.ac.Industry}"/> 
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!a.ac.Phone}" rendered="{!(!a.isSelected)}"/>
                    <apex:column rendered="{!a.isSelected}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!a.ac.Phone}" />
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteSelect}" rendered="{!(!rend)}" rerender="table"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save"  onclick="saveIt(); return false;" rendered="{!rend}" rerender="block"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Edit" onclick="enableEdit(); return false;" rendered="{!(!rend)}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="cancelIt(); return false;" rendered="{!rend}" rerender="block"/>

            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>




/* Controller */

public class CListView {
    //public List<cContact> contactList {get; set;}
    public List<cAccount> accountList {get; set;}
    public List<cAccount> Acc {get; set;}
    public Boolean rend { get; set; }

   public List<cAccount> getAccounts(){

        if(accountList == null) {
            rend = false;
            accountList = new List<cAccount>();
           for(Account a: [select Id, Name, Industry, Phone from Account ]){
               accountList.add(new cAccount(a));
           }
        }
      return accountList;
    }

   public PageReference editSelect() {
       rend=true;
       Acc= new List<cAccount>();
        for(cAccount cAcc: getAccounts()) {
            if(cAcc.isSelected == true) {
                Acc.add(cAcc);
             }
        }
        return null;
   }

   public PageReference deleteSelect() {
        List<Account> selectedAcc= new List<Account>();
        for(cAccount cAcc: getAccounts()) {
            if(cAcc.isSelected == true) {
                selectedAcc.add(cAcc.ac);
             }
        }
        delete selectedAcc;
        accountList=null;
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference saveAcc() {
       List<Account> upAcc= new List<Account>();
       for(cAccount ac: Acc) {
          ac.isSelected = false;
           upAcc.add(ac.ac);
       }
      update upAcc;
      rend=false;
       return null;
   }
     public PageReference cancelAcc() {

       for(cAccount ac: Acc) {
            ac.isSelected = false;
       }
      rend=false;
        return null;
   }

public class cAccount {
        public Account ac {get; set;}
        public Boolean isSelected {get; set;}
        public cAccount(Account a) {
            ac = a;
            isSelected = false;
        }
    }   


}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, and I want to make the VF layouts as the same of the picture of above,could you please alter the VF page?

Comment: sure give me some time